# Don't know the exact problem of NullPoniter

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I am creating a FireBase Phone Authentication app.
I've 2 fragments: 1. for getting the phone number of user 2. for OTP verification.
I wanted to automatically verify the OTP when the EdiText is filed with 6 digits.

I did the exact same as shown in the tutorial.
Kindly help me.

I've read/ tried to understand this:
[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510)

Line 23 and 43 are:

```
private val binding get() = _binding!!
```

and

```
binding.etOtp.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
```

Here is my logcat:

```
--------- beginning of crash
2021-01-27 15:49:44.430 11355-11355/com.techfan.firebasetest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.techfan.firebasetest, PID: 11355
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.techfan.firebasetest.fragments.OTPFragment.getBinding(OTPFragment.kt:23)
        at com.techfan.firebasetest.fragments.OTPFragment.onCreate(OTPFragment.kt:43)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Here what I did so far:

```
class OTPFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentOtpBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    var storedVerificationId: String? = null

    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentOtpBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        storedVerificationId = arguments?.getString("toSend")

        binding.etOtp.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)

        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    }

    private val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            if (start == 6) {
                val otp=binding.etOtp.text.toString().trim()
                if(otp.isNotEmpty()){
                    val credential : PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                        storedVerificationId.toString(), otp)
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this.requireActivity()) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    startActivity(Intent(activity?.applicationContext, DashboardActivity::class.java))
                    activity?.finish()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ADM val storedVerificationId = arguments?.getString("toSend") is for getting the value from another fragment

Comment: @ADM I think var storedVerificationId: String? = null should work

Comment: @ADM I've done those changes still getting same error... Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fragment lifecycle, `onCreate()` comes before `onCreateView()`. You're trying to use `binding` before it is initialised.

Move the code that needs `binding` to `onCreateView()` or a later lifecycle phase.

Comment: I got confused between them. Thanks alot